# php application on two hosts

Tags: php

I have my php-mysql-oracle application hosted on two linux machines. Of late, I've been seeing some issues with my application intermittently. 
The `$_SESSION` variables are sometime populated, sometimes blank. My code also behaves weird. Sometimes a function works and sometimes it doesn't. I'm not able to replicate the issue correctly.

My assumption is `$_SESSION` and `$_POST` are getting mixed up somehow between the session.
Is it really possible for such thing to happen. I dont have session and post variables saved in database.

Comment: I don't think so. There must be bug or something. If I were you, I'd try to log them to further inspection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running on a load balancer? If so, `$_SESSION` data is being saved to disk on one of the machines on the load balancer. Then, when the load balancer switches you to the other machine, the `$_SESSION` data no longer exists, since the session file on disk doesn't exist on that machine.

Comment: Yup. Solutions include saving sessions to a shared storage like a database server, memcached, etc.

Comment: Yes, I'm running this on a load balancer. This might be the problem. But I wondering if this issue is valid for POST data as well? Where is the POST data stored? Web server I suppose? since there are two machines, there are two web servers, does the POST data get jumbled?

Comment: POST data is not stored; it is simply sent to the server with the request. To answer your question, though, I'd need more detail on what exactly the problem with your POST data is.

Comment: my code is too complex to explain here. Thanks for the clarification.